# When using Numbers app, is there a setting to create a new column when user presses tab?

Tags: ms-office, numbers

When you are navigating in Numbers, pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key will take you to the *next cell to the right* and allows you to start typing. Very quick and helpful for data entry. When the user reaches the last column, pressing tab has **no effect**. In MS Excel, pressing tab in the final column will **create a new column** and allow the user to continue.

Is it possible to do the same in numbers or is there always a break in workflow to stop and create new columns manually? Same question applies for enter but for rows. In excel, pressing enter in the final row will add a new row and let the user continue.

Answer (score 1):

To add a row above the selected cells use the Option+Up Arrow command.

To add a row below the selected cells use the Option+Down Arrow command.

To add a column to the right of the selected cells use the Option+Right Arrow command.

To add a column to the left of the selected cells use the Option+Left Arrow command.

On an iPad you can use the next buttons found on the screen
[image: iPad numbers screen]